# Angular2 "Webpack: An Introduction" example does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am following the example an the angular.io site [Webpack: An Introduction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). I have implemented the example exactly as specified in the (quite good) instructions. 
All builds OK. However, when I run this I get an "Uncaught error" (see screen capture below). 
Looks like I am either missing something, or there actually is a problem in this example.

Is there a complete project for this example on the web rather than individual files?

[image]

Comment: @micronyks, I think it should be  `styleUrls` in your comment. `styleUrls: ['first.css', 'second.css']`.

Comment: I don't think there is. there is an official WebPack based seed project [here](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) which might help you get started though.

Comment: It might help if you post also your app component. But anyway double check if you are using `styles` instead of `styleUrls` in your  component. styles is for inline css and styleUrls for external css files.

Comment: Thanks  for pointing me in the right direction. I simply forgot to put code in the app.component.css.